# Searching for strings using mysql regexp

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Hi I want to search for the string that is strongly equals to in mysql table.
Suppose I have following data:

```
 name        skills
 John      HTML^&*HTML5^&*CSS^&*CSS3
 Roman     HTML^&*CSS
 Anrold    CSS^&*CSS3
```

Here  `^&*` is used to parse the content.
How to do regexp search in mysql so that when I search for `HTML5` then it returns only name `John` but not `john and roman`. I tried it using `like` but it didn't worked.

```
 select * from table where skills regexp [HTML]
```

But I would return `HTML5` too. But It should only return rows having `HTML`.

There may be answer to say normalize your table. So it would not be solution for me because above is just the example. It may contains any other fields with options since my project deals with form builder.

Comment: Try `select * from table where skills regexp '[[:<:]]HTML[[:>:]]'`. Or `select * from table where skills regexp '[[:<:]]HTML5[[:>:]]'`

Comment: Maybe if you explain how you use "like" it would give us a hint on why isn't "like" working for you. Because it should...

Comment: @user254153: Perhaps, you need `SELECT * FROM table WHERE skills NOT LIKE '%HTML5%'` if you want the opposite and get `Roman` and `Arnold` entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve this using `like` operator in Mysql as

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE skills LIKE '%HTML5%'
```

and the opposite version of `LIKE` is `NOT LIKE` as

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE skills NOT LIKE '%HTML5%'
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked but how can I do incase of not like. I mean not equal to.